# Flutter – formatting phone number text field

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a text field that properly formats a phone number. I have tried using

`NumberFormat("+# ### ### ####");`

But it doesn't retain spaces

I have tried simplifying it by just adding a `+` to the front but I cannot backspace when I set the offset.

```
class PhoneInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final text = newValue.text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\D'), '');
    final offset = text.length + 1;

    return newValue.copyWith(
      text: text.length >= 1 ? '+$text' : '',
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: offset),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is a package masked_text https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/masked_text

Answer (score 10):

This Should Work :

```
class NumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
    if (newTextLength >= 1) {
      newText.write('+');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 3) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 2) + ' ');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 2) selectionIndex += 1;
    }
    // Dump the rest.
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex)
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    return new TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
final _mobileFormatter = NumberTextInputFormatter();

TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          maxLength: 15,
          inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
            WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            _mobileFormatter,
          ],
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone),
            hintText: "Mobile*",
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Did you grab that from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/text_form_field_demo.dart#L297-L335 ? That only works for USA numbers AFAIK. Also, the delete problem exists in this example too.

Comment: what format you want .? above code Gives - ### ### ####

Comment: E.164 international phone

Comment: Updated the Answer to Support  E.164 formatting: +442071838750

Comment: I want the format to be like this @anmol.majhail : `+7 923 777 77 77`.  `+91 090090909` This is the current result

Answer (score 9):

Here's a light weight approach *(does not work correctly on older Android OS KitKit)* where you can set the specific format you want with the **[MaskedInputFormater](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter#masked-formatter)** class, using the plugin: [flutter_multi_formatter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter)

```
import 'package:flutter_multi_formatter/flutter_multi_formatter.dart';

TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  autocorrect: false,
  inputFormatters: [
    MaskedInputFormater('(###) ###-####')
  ],
  // .. etc
);
```

In my case, app is only domestic to start, so I don't want any international code in the phone number UI.  All the plugins out there seem to expect that.

========================

**Update 1**

Just tested this on the older Android KitKat, and unfortunately doesn't work correctly there.

However, depending on the app and the audience - if you know most users will have a later OS, this is not a bad solution for getting something out there.

Comment: MaskedInputFormatter*

Answer (score 4):

Because of the android keyboard issue, I've had better luck with my own custom  TextInputFormatter. TextFormField has a parameter for inputFormatters which takes a list of formatters. The code I wrote could probably be written in a way that is easier to read without all the ternary operators, but here goes nothing.

```
class InternationalPhoneFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {

  String internationalPhoneFormat(value) {
  String nums = value.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[\D]'), '');
  String internationalPhoneFormatted = nums.length >= 1
    ? '+' + nums.substring(0, nums.length >= 1 ? 1 : null) + (nums.length  > 1 ? ' (' : '') + nums.substring(1, nums.length >= 4 ? 4 : null) 
    + (nums.length  > 4 ? ') ' : '') + (nums.length > 4
      ? nums.substring(4, nums.length >= 7 ? 7 : null) + (nums.length > 7
        ? '-' + nums.substring(7, nums.length >= 11 ? 11 : null)
        : '')
      : '')
    : nums;
    return internationalPhoneFormatted;
  }

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
      String text = newValue.text;

      if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
        return newValue;
      }

      return newValue.copyWith(
        text: internationalPhoneFormat(text),
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: internationalPhoneFormat(text).length)
      );
  }
}
```

Use this class as an inputerFormatter argument for your TextForm Field and it will format it as +x (xxx) xxx-xxxx

Comment: too much easy and modifiable answer

Answer (score 2):

Use the `intl_phone_number_input` package from `pub.dev`. I think it's easy.
follow [this link](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input#-readme-tab-)

Comment: This package is VERY bad and not that useful.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for RU numbers.
We have identical numbers, but written in different ways. 8900.. = +7900..
Also if we start typing with 9, it can automatically become 9.. > +79..

So, this code result will be: +7(900)000-00-00

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class NumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 1;
    final newTextBuffer = StringBuffer();

if (newTextLength >= 1) {
  if (newValue.text.startsWith(RegExp(r'[789]'))) {
    newTextBuffer.write('+7');
    if (newValue.text.startsWith('9')) {
      newTextBuffer.write('(9');
      selectionIndex = 4;
    }
    if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex++;
  }
}

if (newTextLength >= 2) {
  newTextBuffer
      .write('(' + newValue.text.substring(1, usedSubstringIndex = 2));
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 2) selectionIndex++;
}
if (newTextLength >= 5) {
  newTextBuffer.write(
      newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex, usedSubstringIndex = 4) +
          ')');
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 4) selectionIndex++;
}
if (newTextLength >= 8) {
  newTextBuffer.write(
      newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex, usedSubstringIndex = 7) +
          '-');
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 7) selectionIndex++;
}
if (newTextLength >= 10) {
  newTextBuffer.write(
      newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex, usedSubstringIndex = 9) +
          '-');
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 9) selectionIndex++;
}

// Dump the rest.
if (newTextLength > usedSubstringIndex) newTextBuffer.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex, newTextLength));

return TextEditingValue(
  text: newTextBuffer.toString(),
  selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
);


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

(US only but easily modifiable) I would recommend only storing digits in your model and formatting the number specifically for the view. For that, I did the following:

```
/// Human readable version of the phone number
String getFormattedPhoneNumber() {
  if (_phoneNumber.isEmpty) {
    return "";
  }

  String phoneNumber = _phoneNumber;
  bool addPlus = phoneNumber.startsWith("1");
  if (addPlus) phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(1);
  bool addParents = phoneNumber.length >= 3;
  bool addDash = phoneNumber.length >= 8;

  // +1
  String updatedNumber = "";
  if (addPlus) updatedNumber += "+1";

  // (222)
  if (addParents) {
    updatedNumber += "(";
    updatedNumber += phoneNumber.substring(0, 3);
    updatedNumber += ")";
  } else {
    updatedNumber += phoneNumber.substring(0);
    return updatedNumber;
  }

  // 111
  if (addDash) {
    updatedNumber += phoneNumber.substring(3, 6);
    updatedNumber += "-";
  } else {
    updatedNumber += phoneNumber.substring(3);
    return updatedNumber;
  }

  // 3333
  updatedNumber += phoneNumber.substring(6);
  return updatedNumber;
}
```

And in your TextInput onChanged method:

```
void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
  if (phoneNumber.contains("\(") && !phoneNumber.contains("\)")) {
    // Remove the digit the user wanted to remove but couldn't b/c a paren
    // was in the way.
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(0, phoneNumber.length - 1);
  }

  // Only store the actual digits
  phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll(RegExp("[^0-9]"), "");

  // Don't let the user enter more digits than is possible
  int maxLength = phoneNumber.startsWith("1") ? 11 : 10;
  if (phoneNumber.length > maxLength) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(0, maxLength);
  }

  model.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
  
  // Notify the UI to update based on new input
  notifyListeners();
}
```