# Custom TextInputFormatter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm developing a Flutter side project. I've been coding with Fltuter and Dart for quite a bit and I'm trying to make things *look more professional*.
The thing is that I have a register form in which the user is asked for their phone number. My intention is to make the output look like: ### ### #### - for example: 123 456 7890 - while the user is typing.
I've been trying to figure out how does `TextInputFormatter` work yet I can't get the expected results.

Could you please give an example on how to do it?

Cheers

EDIT (Added code snippet):
If tried adding the first space with this (I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](https://dev.to/rubensdemelo/flutter-formatting-textfield-with-textinputformatter-1oii)).

```
class PhoneInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
    TextEditingValue oldValue,
    TextEditingValue newValue,
  ) {
    final String text = newValue.text;
    final int textLength = text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();

    if (textLength < 4) {
      buffer.write(text.substring(0, textLength));
    }

    // ### ### ####
    if (textLength >= 4) {
      buffer.write(text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 2));
      buffer.write(' ');
      buffer.write(text[3]);

      selectionIndex++;
    }

    return newValue.copyWith(
      text: buffer.toString(),
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

*[An image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U13fF.png)*

Comment: The link does not seem to be working, anyway, it is best to give us the code that you have tried, that will make is easier for us to help.

Comment: @Unbreachable Does not work to you? It does to me, it shows the UI. I will post the code.

Comment: Take a look at the  second answer(look at the edits) from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780438/flutter-formatting-phone-number-text-field

Comment: @Unbreachable I've just tried and it keeps adding `+` at the beggining of the input :(

Comment: Did you look at the first post he did? It does not include the '+', but you can simply remove that yourself anyways.

Comment: Now I've seen it. Excuse me. I have finally solved. Thanks! (Should I post how I've done it?).

Comment: Great, no, in this case, it is not necessary to post how you've done it.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52780646) posted on this question which seems similar to your use case. Just **omit** this portion to not add a `+` at the start of the field.

```dart
// Remove this part
if (newTextLength >= 1) {
  newText.write('+');
  if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex++;
}
```