# Flutter TextInputFormatter for US phone numbers E.164 not working. How to format using US (+1) code

Tags: flutter, dart

I am attempting to use Firebase Phone Auth for user login without success. I have tried adding different variation of the TextInputFormatter and continue receiving the firebase error "not formatted correctly, E.164".

```
class NumberTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final int newTextLength = newValue.text.length;
    int selectionIndex = newValue.selection.end;
    int usedSubstringIndex = 0;
    final StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
    if (newTextLength >= 1) {
      newText.write('+');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 1) selectionIndex++;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= 3) {
      newText.write(newValue.text.substring(0, usedSubstringIndex = 2) + '1');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 2) selectionIndex += 1;
    }
    if (newTextLength >= usedSubstringIndex) newText.write(newValue.text.substring(usedSubstringIndex));
    return new TextEditingValue(
      text: newText.toString(),
      selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}

final _uscodeformatter = NumberTextInputFormatter();
```

I am new to Flutter and did not see any documentation for guidance on this. The
current TextInputFormatter returns `+40 43107231` instead of `+14043107231`. I have
tried working the conditional statements like

```
if (newTextLength >= 10) {
      newText.write('1');
      if (newValue.selection.end >= 10) selectionIndex++;
    }
```

Comment: You can take a look at the last answer and his edits. \https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780438/flutter-formatting-phone-number-text-field

Comment: @Unbreachable I have used this answer as basis and the function has not returned a properly formatted E.164 US phone number\